# How to use select in Codeigniter's Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Given the following code:

```
$this->db->select();
```

the parameters in the select function are the names of the columns selected from the data base.

Suppose that one of the parameters inserted is: `COUNT(column_name)`.

Does it mean that only one row will be selected? `(because COUNT returns a single value)`

Comment: Whats your question can you please elaborate

Comment: My question is, suppose that we have $this->db->select(A, B, COUNT(C)); where A, B and C are the names of columns, then if we type $this->db->get()->result(), how many rows do we have?

Comment: @Uchiha: rows, not columns...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(column_name) AS Total, other_column_name');
$this->db->from('Table_name');
```

Comment: Another question, what does COUNT(IF(A IS NOT NULL, B, NULL)) do? Where A and B are column names.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that only one row will be selected ? (because COUNT
>   returns a single value)

Of course yes, only one row will be selected, since the count is an aggregate operator, which makes only one row returned.

Please note using an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY` will always return one row, no matter what. You must use a `GROUP BY` if you want to return more than one row.

For more details read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)